# How should I write this function $f:\mathcal P_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})\to \mathcal P_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, ordinals

How should I most clearly define the function that $f:\mathcal P_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})\to \mathcal P_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})$ which maps certain subsets of the power set of $\omega^{<\omega}$ to singletons, by deleting the smallest term of any ordinal (written in Cantor normal form) and reducing the exponent of all other terms by one:

$f:\displaystyle \bigcup_{s_1\in X}\{\omega^{b-1}\cdot s_1+\omega^{b-2}\cdot s_2+\ldots s_b:s_b \in X\subseteq\Bbb N\}\mapsto \{\omega^{b-2}\cdot s_1+\omega^{b-3}\cdot s_2+\ldots s_{b-1}\}$

Where $X\subseteq N$ and $s_b$ are drawn from $\Bbb N$?

Then this is surjective over $\mathcal P_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})$ which indicates the subset of the power set, containing only *finite* sets of finite strings of naturals.

If this isn't clear, how best do I write this function so as to be clear?

Is "contraction mapping" an appropriate name for this function given that it must eventually terminate?

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathcal P(\omega^{<\omega})$ here?

Comment: @Wojowu definitively I'm talking about $\omega^{<\omega}$ being the set of strings of positive integers of unlimited length but I'm pretty sure the ordinals I've given in Cantor normal form express this as the set of all ordinals less than $\omega^{\omega}$. Then $\mathcal P(\omega^{<\omega})$ is its power set.

Comment: There's one thing I know I'm not doing so well here, and that's for $f$ to be well-defined over over all of $\mathcal P(\omega^{<\omega})$ then I should probably better express how it will map certain sets to non-singletons

Comment: For any given set, are all the $s$'s except the first the same or do they and $b$ range over all of $\Bbb N$?  If $X$ were $\{1,2,3\}$ would the set have three elements with $b$ and the larger $s_i$ the same, or would it be all ordinals with  the largest term having a coefficient of $1,2,$ or $3$?  In any case it is not injective as $\omega+1$ and $\omega+2$ both go to $1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, sorry re injective that was silly. $f(\{\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\omega^2\cdot3\})=\{1,\omega\cdot 3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your written definition of the function, there are several things that are unclear; for example, I don't really understand the emphasis on $s_1$ over the other terms, or how you're interpreting "$\bigcup$." I also don't understand your claim that it maps sets to singletons, given your example $\{\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\omega^2\cdot 3\}\mapsto\{1,\omega\cdot 3\}$.

Based on your example in the comments, though, I suspect that what you're asking for is the following. I'll first build it in stages, rather than describing it all at once, and then give an all-at-once definition below.

*Incidentally, it does **not** always terminate; e.g. $f(\{\omega^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\})=\{\omega^n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ if I understand it correctly. Maybe you want to look at $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})$ - the set of* finite *sets of finite strings of naturals - instead of $\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega})$? Also, the term "contraction mapping" has a technical meaning in the study of metric spaces, which this could conceivably fit but only after you've defined an appropriate metric structure.*

---

- First, let $C: \omega^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega^\omega$ be the *Cantor normal form* function, sending a finite string of naturals to the ordinal $<\omega^\omega$ which it represents. *(Note that $C$ is noninjective - for example, it sends both $\langle 0,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1\rangle$ to $1$ - so if you want an injection, it will be a slight modification of the obvious $C$.)*
- Next, we have the *truncation function* $$trun:\omega^{<\omega}\setminus\{\langle\rangle\}\rightarrow\omega^{<\omega}: \langle a_1,..., a_n\rangle\mapsto \langle a_1,..., a_{n-1}\rangle.$$ *Note that this isn't defined on the empty string; if you prefer, you could define it to be the identity on the empty string, that is, set $trun(\langle\rangle)=\langle\rangle$.*
- Next, we have the *pointwise version* of your $f$: $$g:\omega^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega^{<\omega}: C(\sigma)\mapsto C(trunc(\sigma)).$$ This does what you want on a single finite string of ordinals; e.g. $$g(\omega^2+\omega)=g(C\langle1,1,0\rangle)=C(trunc(\langle 1,1,0\rangle))=\omega+1.$$ *Note that we have to show that $g$ is actually well-defined - that is, if $C(\alpha)=C(\beta)$ then $C(trunc(\alpha))=C(trunc(\beta))$ - but this is easy.*
- Finally, your $f$ is the "set version" of $g$: $$f:\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega})\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega}): S\mapsto\{g(s): s\in S\}.$$

---

OK, now here's the all-at-once definition: $f$ is the function from $\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega})$ to $\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega})$ which sends a set $X$ to the set

$$\{\omega^n\cdot s_{n+1}+\omega^{n-1}\cdot s_n+...+\omega^0\cdot s_1: \exists t(\omega^{n+1}\cdot s_{n+1}+\omega^{n}\cdot s_n+...+\omega^{1}\cdot s_1+t\in X)\}.$$

Comment: Thank-you. I can't believe something so easy to say "delete the smallest term of any ordinal (in Cantor normal form) and reduce the exponent of all other terms" is so difficult for me to work out how to write clearly.

Comment: One final thing... this always terminates on iteration, and... is it okay to call it a contraction mapping?

Comment: ...PPS why do you have $C: \omega^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega^\omega$ rather than$C: \omega^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega^{<\omega}$?

Comment: @RobertFrost $C$ is the function that takes in a finite string and outputs the *ordinal it names*, so it's a map from $\omega^{<\omega}$ to $\omega^\omega$. As I explained, however, $f$ does **not** always terminate on iteration (unless you change $\mathcal{P}(\omega^{<\omega})$ to $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\omega^{<\omega})$, that is, restrict the domain to *finite* sets of finite sequences), and since the term "contraction mapping" already has meaning, it would be incorrect to use it here, unless you establish that it does in fact fit that definition. I would call it a "truncation map," personally.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the modification to make $C$ injective is simply to choose only from positive naturals, and then to send $C$ to the ordinal one less than the Cantor normal form? So we have e.g. $(1)\mapsto 0...(1,1)\mapsto\omega...(2,1)\mapsto\omega\cdot2...(2,2)\mapsto\omega\cdot2+1\ldots$?